# Simplify this document.referrer check

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can this be simplified in any way?

```
if ($('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page1.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page2.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page3.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page4.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page5.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page6.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('page7.html') > 0) ||
    $('.content').length && (document.referrer.search('search/?') > 0)) {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
};
```

Comment: It'd help if you can explain what you are doing here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easily! You can use a regular expression to match `page[1-7].html` and also `search/?`:

```
if ($('.content').length && document.referrer.match(/page[1-7]\.html|search\/\?/)) {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
};
```

And never write conditions in such wasteful way:

> ```
> if (A && B || A && C || A && D) {
> ```

when it can be easily simplified to:

```
if (A && (B || C || D)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer of [@janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61452/49695) is great for this case, but as a more general answer (and if you want to avoid regular expressions):

If you have logic like this:

```
(A && B) || (A && C) || (A && D)
```

Because `and` and `or` are distributive, you can rewrite it as:

```
A && (B || C || D)
```

And of course you can always extract long repeating code to its own function. If you apply both ideas, you would get:

```
if ($('.content').length && 
    (search('page1.html') || search('page2.html') || [...] || search('search/?')) {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
};

function search(page) {
    return document.referrer.search(page) > 0;
}
```